# Why do people so often use "jive" when they actually mean "jibe"?

Tags: american-english, homophones

I often hear people use the word "jive" when I'm pretty sure they mean "jibe."  It's a subtle sound difference so it's hard to catch.  But why do so many people mix these two up?

Comment: Reminds me of the Simpson's episode where Homer asks [What's a gym?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4i8SpNgzA4)

Comment: You mean people are launching jives at you?  And this is a problem?

Comment: To save people a lookup: http://www.beedictionary.com/common-errors/gibe_vs_jibe_vs_jive - even the BeeGees got it wrong ;)

Comment: I didn't know what either word meant until this thread made me look them up.

Comment: I have always explained the confusion to myself as being because *jive* can mean to dance and when two things don’t *jibe* they can be thought of as figuratively not dancing well together.

Comment: The harder distinction in my opinion is knowing whether it's "gibe" or "jibe". "Your figures jibe with mine." Also: "jibe, variant of gibe", as in to tease.

Comment: Probably never been on a sailboat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would assume that the primary cause is the similarity in sounds. "Jibe" and "jive" sound close enough you could mishear one for the other; once enough people get it mixed up it sticks. "Jive" probably got the benefit of the doubt in people's minds because English has more "-ive" words than "-ibe."

For what it is worth, I didn't know it was supposed to be "jibe." Everyone I know says "jive." If it bugs you, kindly point it out in the style of trivia: "Did you know the word actually has a *b* in it? Most people say it with a *v* but I saw it written and..." People who care will learn; those who don't get to be wrong. But if enough people are wrong for a long enough time they become right... so hedge your bets accordingly.

Comment: I agree with this, except I would predict that the likely cause is simply that the *word* "jive" is much more common than "jibe" (rather than generalizing about "-ive" and "-ibe", though it could be that too).

Comment: @Kos: But how did "jive" get much more common? Now that the error has stuck it makes sense that it gets passed around. The -ive/-ibe is just a guess but without knowing "jibe" in particular I would probably have assumed they meant "jive" or are mispronouncing "jib."

Comment: What I mean is, "jive" just happened to be more common already in its own domain (and its meaning made it so that it wasn't such a huge stretch to be used where "jibe" is supposed to be used). I was thinking of something similar to [folk etymologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_etymology).

Comment: @Kos: Ah, yes. I completely agree. I debated mentioning that in the answer and decided it was pushing a little too much conjecture into such a small space. Since you pointed it out anyway, everything went better than expected. :)

Comment: For me, yes, "Jibe" just doesn't sound like a real word, but "Jive" is and it kind of makes sense. A jive is an upbeat, flowing song and dance where the dance involves coordinated cooperation. It's not a large leap to assume it's synonymous with "groove". "We're in the groove. We're jiving."

Answer (score 4):

I found an interesting [Maven's word of the day article](http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=20000711) sharing the differences between "jive", "jibe" and "gibe". The misuse is so common now that at least one dictionary doesn't mention this fact.

---

From [internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130116223500/http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=20000711):

> July 11, 2000 - jibe/gibe/jive
>
> Mark Wickens wrote:
>
> > A common confusion I hear is the use of **jive** for **jibe**, as in "His story doesn't jive with the facts." That should be **jibe**, right? Are the two words related at all?
>
> In your example, **jibe** means 'to be in harmony or accord; to agree'. The origin of this term is uncertain; it may be related to the similarly spelled **jibe** in the sense 'to shift a sail from one side to the other while sailing before the wind'. This sailing term was borrowed from a Dutch verb, and is also spelled **gybe**, especially in British English.
>
> The accepted meanings of **jive** are 'to tease or bluff' or 'to dance to jazz or swing music.' The origin of this term is "obscure," a few degrees cloudier than "uncertain." Using **jive** as a variant of **jibe** in the meaning 'to agree' is usually considered an error or misspelling, though the "error" is so common that at least one college dictionary (not Random House) enters it without comment or warning label. The confusion between these two words is not new in the language. The journal **American Speech** records **jive** in a list of college slang from the 1940s: "Doesn't jive. Doesn't make sense." The **Dictionary of American Regional English** has many examples of the "error" from the 1950s through the 1960s. **Jibe** and **jive** are still commonly confused, as in this recent example from **The Washington Times**: "Their initial numbers just didn't jive, just didn't pass the initial smell test."
>
> The general opinion on the jibe/jive issue is summed up in this example from a 1980 edition of The Daily News: "Can you take seriously as a writer anyone who refers to 'the welfare roles of this country' and reports that everything a character said 'had jived with the facts'? Such a person may be taken seriously only as a symptom of decay in our language." (To protect the guilty, I won't divulge the writer's identity).
>
> A further confusion exists between the identically pronounced **jibe** and **gibe**. In the sense 'to mock or jeer', the preferred spelling is **gibe**, especially in formal writing, but **jibe** is an acceptable spelling variant. In the senses 'to agree' and 'to shift a sail to the other side...', **gibe** is occasionally used instead of **jibe**, but is usually considered an error.
>
> Adding to the confusion is the fact that **gibe**/**jibe** in the sense 'to mock or jeer' is semantically similar to **jive** in the sense 'to tease or bluff'. So, error or not, these spelling and sense distinctions among **jibe**, **gibe**, and **jive** are very difficult to keep straight. My advice is to have a copy of this Word of the Day handy at all times.
>
> Carol

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking "not to jibe" comes from sailing language, meaning "it (your argument) doesn't make headway very well against a headwind (of opposing argument):

A jibe (US) or gybe (Britain) is a sailing maneuver whereby a sailing vessel reaching downwind turns its stern through the wind, such that the wind direction changes from one side of the boat to the other. For square-rigged ships, this maneuver is called wearing ship.

Comment: That gives some background to the word 'jibe', but can you explain the confusion of it with 'jive'?

Comment: "Age of sail" was roughly 1570's -1860's.  "A jibe"/"to jibe" would have been common to most people. 1860's -1920's it was used less as sailing terms lost currency. 1920's, African-Americans brought "jive" into US English as "to deceive playfully"  Like so many African-American additions to the American-English language, and "jive" became wildly popular. The meanings of "to deceive" and "To offer a poor argument" became commingled in people's minds, but "jive" being more recently popular and simply "cooler sounding", won out in being used more often then "jibe" in the U.S. vernacular today.

Comment: The above is pure speculation on my part, but sounds pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: You should add all that to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of a large collection of errors of this type. ("Tact" for "tack" is one that I particularly note.) My observation is that people mis-hear something, understand the meaning from the context, but have no clue about the etymology. They then simply repeat what they believe to be the correct phrase, and it is propagated.

Most of us don't research where phrases come from when we first learn them. Certainly not in our early years when we acquire the largest part of our working vocabulary.

Comment: See also [eggcorns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) and [mondegreens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen).

Comment: cole slaw/cold slaw. Duct tape/duck tape. Bated breath/Baited breath.

Answer (score -1):

The words jibe and jive are often confused with each other. To complicate matters, jibe is an accepted alternative spelling of the word gibe and vice-versa. In U.S. popular culture, since at least the 1970s, the African-American slang term jive (“You’re jiving me” or “You jive turkey”) has stuck in the minds of many and has likely displaced jibe in usage. Because there are subtle differences in meanings, it helps to focus on first or primary definitions of the words themselves. The word jibe as a verb is first defined as follows: “if two things jibe, they agree or contain similar information” (all definitions, in quotes, are from the online version of Macmillan Dictionary). The first definition of the word jive as a verb is “to dance a jive.” The second definition of jive as a verb is “to tell someone something that you know is not true.” The word jibe as a noun is first defined as “a comment that is intended to annoy or offend someone.” The word gibe as a noun is first defined as “a remark that is intended to hurt someone or to make them feel stupid.” Macmillan does not provide a definition for gibe as a verb. In summary, the grammatical evidence supports the correct usage of jibe, not jive, as a verb to mean two things agreeing or containing similar information.

Answer (score -5):

I understand that allowing a word to be used incorrectly leads to its increased standardardizaization. In East Texas, where I grew up, as well as northern Alabama, where I presently live, the following is standard American English: "When I seen the airplane, it was falling out of the sky." It is not 50% of the time that they get it right, it's wrong 100% of the time. I find this curious! I guess one day, this will be as acceptable as "ain't", which I heard VP Joe Biden use on the Jay Leno Garage TV show, when showing off his vintage Corvette. There's a good reason for ain't, though, because there "ain't" a good contraction for am not. So I think thatit is entirely different. The use of of jive instead of jibe indicated a lack of knowledge of the source of the words. Curiously, though, many people who should know better make this mistake.  Certainly, they know the meaning of jive, and should recognize that it clearly doesn't fit the usage where the meaning is something closer to "be consistent with", where jive is clearly inappropriate in this usage.

Another thing that I have noticed in the same two areas mentioned is is a strange use of "license" as a plural word! As in "I lost my driver's license, but finally found them".

I can't accept that jibe and jive are only "subtly different" in meaning. Jibe comes from nautical usage and jive is African American slang, with very different meaning. Nor do I approve of dictionary acceptance of slang misuse of words. I believe this could contribute to the erosion of our language. There is slang and there is proper English-- at least in my mind! Neither can I accept that gibe and jibe are acceptable spelling of the same words. They have obviously very different meanings. Gibe, noun or verb, means to be negative in an intentional way. Jibe's current major meaning is to fit consistently with. Unless you like to sail!

Comment: « I believe this could contribute to the erosion of our language. » — You believe incorrectly. This sort of thing has been happening in every single natural, spoken language on each for as long as language has existed. It will always exist. It is a natural part of how languages change and evolve. Languages erode and disappear for many reasons, but reinterpretations is not one of them.

Comment: So, you speak English exactly as it is written, i.e., before it was eroded by [the Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift)?