# A rare meaning of the word "to jive"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I was reading [an article](https://qz.com/986969/many-workers-at-world-changing-tech-companies-might-as-well-work-at-walmart/) and suddenly stumbled on a strange use of the word "jive":

> Since 2014, according to the report, hundreds of ambulances have been called to the factory to treat workers.
>
> This portrayal doesn’t quite **jive with** Musk’s world-changing vision.

Google provided the next reference about meanings of the word and I do not see anything appropriate to the example from the article:

> jive /dʒʌɪv/
>
> noun: jive; plural noun: jives; noun: jive talk; plural noun: jive talks
>
> 1. a lively style of dance popular especially in the 1940s and 1950s, performed to swing music or rock and roll.
>
>    swing music.
>
>    a style of dance music popular in South Africa.
> 2. a form of slang associated with black American jazz musicians.
>
>    North American informal; deceptive or worthless talk.
>
> verb: jive; 3rd person present: jives; past tense: jived; past participle: jived; gerund or present participle: jiving
>
> 1. perform the jive or a similar dance to popular music.
> 2. North American informal; taunt or sneer at.
>
>    talk nonsense.
>
> adjective: jive
>
> 1. deceitful or worthless.
>
> Origin
>   1920s (originally US denoting meaningless or misleading speech): of unknown origin; the later musical sense ‘jazz’ gave rise to ‘dance performed to jazz’ (1940s).

The meaning of "**to jive with**" from the article must be something like "*to correlate with*", but there is nothing similar in the Google reference.

---

So my questions are:

- what is the meaning of "to jive with" in the article?
- whether this meaning is widespread and common or is it some exception?

Comment: To jive means to correspond to. The portrayal does not correspond to the vision. Yes, it is very used. You see it all the time in many different contexts.  It must have with accompanying it. X jives with Y.

Comment: Never use the first thing on google. Also, similarly, never use one dictionary. Check at least three dictionaries. Really, it's the 21st century, it's pretty easy.

Comment: Not rare at all.  I'd say that use is more common in the US than the musical sense.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20633/why-do-people-so-often-use-jive-when-they-actually-mean-jibe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***To jive*** meaning to agree with appears to be mainly an  AmE usage according to the following sources. Note that jive and jibe are often used interchangeably in that respect:.

Usage notes from [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/jive):

> - "Jive" and "jibe" have been used interchangeably in the US to indicate the concept ***"to agree or accord."*** While one recent dictionary accepts this usage of "jive," most sources consider it to be in error.

***[To jive and jibe](http://americanenglishdoctor.com/wordpress/jive-and-jibe):***

> ***According to the American dictionary Merriam-Webster, jibe is an intransitive verb meaning “to be in accord [with]***” and gives as examples:
>
> - his account of the accident jibes pretty well with other accounts;
>     their inferior status did not jibe with democratic ideals…
>
>   This same American dictionary gives two definitions for jive as a verb:
> - *to talk jive, or to fool around
>     to dance to hot jazz, or to play hot jazz*
>
> ***The British Oxford English Dictionary flags jibe in the sense of “to agree with” as “chiefly U.S.”*** Unlike Merriam-Webster, however, the OED includes this definition under the word jive:

(americanenglishdoctor.com)

Also [Grammarphobia](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/02/jibe-gibe-jive.html) notes about this typical AmE usage:

> - As you’ve noticed, ***“jive” is often used for “jibe”*** in the sense of agreement, though no authoritative dictionary considers this usage standard English.
> - The verb “jibe,” is a nautical term that refers to changing course by shifting a fore-and-aft sail from side to side while sailing before the wind. (Remember, British dictionaries spell the word “gybe.”)
> - ***However, “jibe” has another meaning that’s not etymologically related to the nautical usage: to agree or be consistent with,***  as in, *“Those figures don’t jibe.”* The Oxford English Dictionary describes ***this usage as “chiefly U.S.”***

and the same usage is confirmed also the the [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/gibe-jibe-jive/):

> - ***Jibe*** has a nautical use (relating to turning the sail to go on an opposite tack), but it’s ***most often used to mean agree or to be in accord.***

Comment: I wouldn't trust anything from Wiktionary with further corroboration, and your *second* source ("americanenglishdoctor") seems flaky, to say the least. She correctly cites OED as including **jive** *1 b. intr. To make sense; to fit in. **U.S.** Cf. **jibe** v*, but completely ignores the fact that both the entire entry ***and*** that specific subdefinition explicitly say it's ***U.S.*** She somehow manages to conclude from that: *Apparently the mistaken use of “jive” for **jibe** has become so widespread that it’s on the road to becoming acceptable. At least from a British viewpoint.* Tosh.

Comment: @FF - if you have a better answer I suggest you post I it instead  of commenting.

Comment: Actually, I'd consider "jibe" to be the erroneous use.

Comment: I'm not qualified to say how Americans (AAVE?) might distinguish or conflate ***jive/jibe*** - I'm just pointing out that I think your source is completely mistaken in claiming that conflation is *so widespread that it’s on the road to becoming acceptable **from a British viewpoint.*** Maybe literate Americans don't think of this as a "dialectal / erroneous" conflation, but I'd have thought practically all Brits do.

Comment: ...it could be relevant that there's a higher proportion of *Spanish* speakers in the US than the UK, and so far as I know they don't distinguish ***v*** from ***b*** in any context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The Spanish v/b thing is irrelevant to this, in my opinion.  Also, what you said about the lack of distinction between v and b is too much of a blanket statement, and it leaves out the various factors that result in a V sound or a B sound in a particular context.  But forget I said that.  Basically, Spanish V/B is irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: @aparente001: Well, the conflation of ***jibe/jive*** certainly looks like a straightforward "**copying** error" to me, so I don't see how you can be so emphatic that this *can't* be affected by the possibility that millions of US speakers are at the very least *liable* to think of ***b/v*** as more "similar-sounding" than true dyed-in-the-wool native Anglophones would think. Not that I'm seriously pressing the case for this being a significant factor; I'm just wondering how you can be so sure it's *not*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It would make a nice challenge question for the etymology detectives on this site.  I am not 100% on this, but I have strong feeling about it.  Jibe/jive came out of African American culture, predating the massive latino diaspora.  Also the latino diaspora has not had much effect on English yet.  I am constantly amazed to see how deaf most anglos are to Spanish even when it is spoken around them on a daily basis.

Comment: @aparente001: I see no mention of *Spanish* on the earlier question being cited as a dup, which suggests no-one else thinks it's relevant. But I've endorsed those closevotes myself now, so I don't suppose *this* page will get a lot more attention. Most of the answers/comments on the first Q seem to agree it's basically a "copying error" arising from mishearing, which is essentially my position.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm confused.  Here comes a stupid question from a person with an unreliable memory: was this the page where you voted to close as duplicate?  I don't see any close votes currently on this page.

Comment: @aparente001:  *You're confused?*. Here comes another stupid question from another person with an unreliable memory *Did I just imagine I closevoted yesterday?* As soon as I've clicked "Add Comment" here, I'm gonna try doing it (***again?!*** :)

Comment: Now I'm really confused. I can't closevote because (as expected) I've already done so. The question was presumably fully closed by my vote, then reopened (by a mod?), but there's no record of this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I can't vote to close either because I already did two days ago.  At least now I'm not feeling so disoriented.  Do you want to ask a Meta question?  I can't find any traces of the roller coaster this question has been on and I don't know why it was reopened.